# Which mysql server package should I install?

Tags: mysql

I posted this question on serverfault but have not received an answer. Maybe someone here can answer this:

I just switched hosts and now have the task of reinstalling everything. I'm on CentOS now and I need to install mysql but have no idea which package to install. I can't seem to find any info on the differences either. Would anyone know? Yum is not an option as it wants to install 5.0.77 and this is too old. The machine is 64 bit.

Comment: I recommend the latest version: 5.1.44.

Comment: Exactly Travis but which package do I choose from the MySQL site? There are like 20 different packages to choose from and I need to get the one that will install on my OS

Answer (score 0):

5.0 is [not supported](http://www.mysql.com/about/legal/lifecycle/#calendar) anymore (unless you have a contract). 5.1 is the only GA-version with support, the only option you have for a free MySQL-database with support.